# Popluating list view with database

Tags: android, database, listview

i try to make my list view appear my data which is saves in database

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ImageView contactImage;
    final EditText nametxt, emailTxt, phoneTxt, addressTxt;
    nametxt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    emailTxt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    phoneTxt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
    addressTxt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
    dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    contactListView=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    contactListView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);

    final Button addBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://org.intracode.contactmanager/drawable/no_user_logo.png");
            import_fragment.Contact contact = new import_fragment.Contact(dbHandler.getContactsCount(), String.valueOf(nametxt.getText()), String.valueOf(phoneTxt.getText()), String.valueOf(emailTxt.getText()), String.valueOf(addressTxt.getText()), imageUri);
            if (!contactExists(contact)) {
                dbHandler.createContact(contact);
                Contacts.add(contact);
                if (contactAdapter != null) contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(nametxt.getText()) + " has been added to your Contacts!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                resetAddContactPanel();
                return;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(nametxt.getText()) + " already exists. Please use a different name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



    final Button addContact = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnadd);

    nametxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            addContact.setEnabled(!nametxt.getText().toString().trim().equals(""));


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });


    return view;


}

ArrayAdapter<import_fragment.Contact> contactAdapter;
ListView contactListView;
DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
int longClickedItemIndex;



public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://org.intracode.contactmanager/drawable/no_user_logo.png");
    ImageView contactImageImgView;
    contactImageImgView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ivContactImage);

    if (resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (reqCode == 1) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            contactImageImgView.setImageURI(data.getData());
        }
    }
}


private void resetAddContactPanel() {
    final EditText nametxt, emailTxt, phoneTxt, addressTxt;
    nametxt = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    emailTxt = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    phoneTxt = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
    addressTxt = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
    nametxt.setText("");
    phoneTxt.setText("");
    emailTxt.setText("");
    addressTxt.setText("");
}

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);

    {
        ImageView contactImageImgView;

        contactImageImgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivContactImage);

        contactImageImgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Contact Image"), 1);
            }

        });


        if (dbHandler.getContactsCount() != 0)
            Contacts.addAll(dbHandler.getAllContacts());

        populateList();
    }


    menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.pencil_icon);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Contact Options");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, EDIT, menu.NONE, "Edit Contact");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE, menu.NONE, "Delete Contact");
}


public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case EDIT:
            // TODO: Implement editing a contact
            break;
        case DELETE:
            dbHandler.deleteContact(Contacts.get(longClickedItemIndex));
            Contacts.remove(longClickedItemIndex);
            contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}



private boolean contactExists(import_fragment.Contact contact) {

    String name = contact.getName();
    int contactCount = Contacts.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < contactCount; i++) {
        if (name.compareToIgnoreCase(Contacts.get(i).getName()) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}


private void populateList() {
    contactAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(getActivity());
    contactListView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
}


final List<import_fragment.Contact> Contacts = new ArrayList<import_fragment.Contact>();

private class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<import_fragment.Contact> {
    public ContactListAdapter(Context cntx) {
        super(cntx, R.layout.fragment_import, Contacts);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null)
            view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_import, parent, false);

        import_fragment.Contact currentContact = Contacts.get(position);

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        name.setText(currentContact.getName());
        TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        phone.setText(currentContact.getPhone());
        TextView email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
        email.setText(currentContact.getEmail());
        TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cAddress);
        address.setText(currentContact.getAddress());


        return view;
    }
}
```

i getting null error in this line `contactListView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);`
Here is DatabaseHelper

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactManager",
        TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts",
        KEY_ID = "id",
        KEY_NAME = "name",
        KEY_PHONE = "phone",
        KEY_EMAIL = "email",
        KEY_ADDRESS = "address",
        KEY_IMAGEURI = "imageUri";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PHONE + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGEURI + " TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    onCreate(db);
}

public void createContact(import_fragment.Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PHONE, contact.getPhone());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contact.getEmail());
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, contact.getAddress());
    values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, contact.getImageURI().toString());

    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}


public import_fragment.Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PHONE, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_IMAGEURI }, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null );

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    import_fragment.Contact contact = new import_fragment.Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5)));
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return contact;
}

public void deleteContact(import_fragment.Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.getId())});
    db.close();
}

public int getContactsCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    return count;
}

public int updateContact(import_fragment.Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PHONE, contact.getPhone());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contact.getEmail());
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, contact.getAddress());
    values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, contact.getImageURI().toString());

    int rowsAffected = db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getId()) });
    db.close();

    return rowsAffected;
}

public List<import_fragment.Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<import_fragment.Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<import_fragment.Contact>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            contacts.add(new import_fragment.Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(5))));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return contacts;
}
```

Here is logcat

```
01-27 07:45:45.795 3034-3034/com.al3almya.users.al3almya E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.al3almya.users.al3almya, PID: 3034
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.al3almya.users.al3almya/com.al3almya.users.al3almya.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.al3almya.users.al3almya.main_fragment.onCreateView(main_fragment.java:65)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is import_fragment.xml [list view here] not in main_fragment.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/ivContactImage" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contact Name"
        android:id="@+id/contactName"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone"
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email"
        android:id="@+id/emailAddress"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Address"
        android:id="@+id/cAddress"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

i added all things but i now want to know how to appear my data in list view please give me code don't tell me setAdapter because when i set it i get error,
Thank you in advance

Comment: you have written `contactListView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);` 2 times in your code, so in which occurence you are getting nullpointer?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya updated my topic

Comment: i think, you did not instantiate contactAdapter in onCreateView, hence it get null

Comment: @RRR if i replace it with populateList() , i will get same error too

Comment: @USKMobility how to instantiate  it then ?

Comment: Post your `fragment_main` xml here.

Comment: override the getCount method in your ContactListAdapter class

Comment: you don't have a `Listview` in `main_fragment` so when you are trying to get object of a listview `contactListView=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);` it is *null* and you are getting this error  while trying to setadaptor on **null** referance of a listview so **add a listview** in your `xml` first

Comment: Okay please anyone Can  tell me what can i add in onCreateView in import_fragment to make it works ?

Answer (score 0):

You are searching `listview` in `main_fragment` and in `main_fragment` `list view` is not available that is why it is giving null pointer exception.

Comment: Okay what can i do now to fix this and let list view appear?

Comment: first debug your code I think your list view is null instead of contactAdapter . please debug and check

Comment: and move your populateList in oncreateview instead onCreateContextMenu

Comment: as you get same error mentioned in your comment I think you should check for your list view. I think your list view is null . please debug and check

Comment: i moved it to onCreateView but i get null error in it, i think list view is null not contactAdapter too, any help ?

Comment: yes that is what I mentioned it in my earlier comment please debug your code and check whether your list view in null and also post your xml file for layout

Comment: i added this line  ListView ListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
 and here is my logcat 'Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.al3almya.users.al3almya.main_fragment.populateList(main_fragment.java:215)
                                                                               at com.al3almya.users.al3almya.main_fragment.onCreateView(main_fragment.java:66)'

Comment: add your xml please for your fragment_main.

Comment: @MaystroJeKa hey you dont have list view in xml that is why list view coming null

Comment: my list view in import_fragment and not main_fragment

Comment: than why you are passing view that is of main_fragment .

Comment: you have to get import_fragment and search list view in that

Comment: Can u tell me what can i add in onCreateView in import_fragment to make it works ?

Comment: what is import_fragment layout for if you can put listview in main_fragment it will work well.

Comment: Because in main_fragment boxs to add new contact to database and import_fragment for appear list view, any help to make it appear ?

Answer (score 0):

*You have any object on your main_fragment line 65 whose refrence is null`at com.al3almya.users.al3almya.main_fragment.onCreateView(main_fragment.java:65)`*